# Upcasting and downcasting with interface?

Tags: java

How will I be able to upcast from a class type to the interface type, and downcast from the interface type to the class type? May you show me how to do this using the example below. Also can someone explain when will you need to upcast and when will you need to downcast?

```
public interface A {

    void display();

}

class B implements A {

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("in class B");
    }

}

class C implements A {

    public void display() {
        System.out.println("in class C");

}
```

Comment: I get the feeling you'd run into a `ClassCastException` if you really wanted to try this.  Why do you feel that you need to do this?

Comment: I just need an example of what upcasting and down casting are. I just put that code for people can use it as an example. I just better understand how to upcast and downcast and when will you need to do it?

Comment: @Makoto Can you explain to me what a ClassCastException is?